# Linked list traversal after reversing the linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list, void-pointers, reversing

I've been trying to run this linkedListTraversal() function after reversing the linked list using the function reverseLinkedList(). I know that I'm applying the correct logic in the reverseLinkedList() function. But for some reason i'm getting the output as something like this
[image: My Output]

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{  
   int data;
   struct Node *next;
};
// struct Node *head;

void linkedListTraversal(struct Node *ptr) 
{
// struct Node *ptr = head;
   while (ptr != NULL)
   {
       printf("Element: %d\n", ptr->data);
       ptr = ptr->next;
   }
}

void reverseLinkedList(struct Node *head)
{
    struct Node *prevNode = NULL;
    struct Node *currNode = head;
    struct Node *nextNode;

    while (currNode != NULL)
    {
       nextNode = currNode->next;
       currNode->next = prevNode;
       prevNode = currNode;
       currNode = nextNode;
    }

    head = prevNode;
}

int main()
{
    struct Node *head;
    struct Node *second;
    struct Node *third;

    head = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    second = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    third = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    head->data = 1;
    head->next = second;

    second->data = 2;
    second->next = third;

    third->data = 3;
    third->next = NULL;

    printf("Linked list before reversal: \n");
    linkedListTraversal(head);

    reverseLinkedList(head);

    printf("Linked list after reversal: \n");
    linkedListTraversal(head);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: pass the address to `reverseLinkedList(&head);` & update head value to reflect. OR return new `head` value from `reverseLinkedList()` to update the `head` in caller function.

Comment: As an aside - you have memory leaks (you never free your nodes).

Answer (score 2):

You're *not* passing back the *updated* `head` to `main`.

The easiest way is to `return` the `head`:

```
struct Node *reverseLinkedList(struct Node *head);
```

And have `main` do:

```
head = reverseLinkedList(head);
```

---

*Side note:* No need to cast the results of `malloc`: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) Here's a more idiomatic way to allocate (e.g.):

```
head = malloc(sizeof(*head));
```

---

Here's the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

// struct Node *head;

void
linkedListTraversal(struct Node *ptr)
{
// struct Node *ptr = head;
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        printf("Element: %d\n", ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

struct Node *
reverseLinkedList(struct Node *head)
{
    struct Node *prevNode = NULL;
    struct Node *currNode = head;
    struct Node *nextNode;

    while (currNode != NULL) {
        nextNode = currNode->next;
        currNode->next = prevNode;
        prevNode = currNode;
        currNode = nextNode;
    }

    head = prevNode;

    return head;
}

int
main(void)
{
    struct Node *head;
    struct Node *second;
    struct Node *third;

    head = malloc(sizeof(*head));
    second = malloc(sizeof(*second));
    third = malloc(sizeof(*third));

    head->data = 1;
    head->next = second;

    second->data = 2;
    second->next = third;

    third->data = 3;
    third->next = NULL;

    printf("Linked list before reversal: \n");
    linkedListTraversal(head);

    head = reverseLinkedList(head);

    printf("Linked list after reversal: \n");
    linkedListTraversal(head);

    return 0;
}
```